# How to generate a json file from a named list in Python?

Tags: python, json, list

Suppose I have a list with named fields, as follows, and want to generate a json file from it.

```
  myListOfPeople =[  
   {  
      'ID':0,
      'Name':'Mary',
      'Age':25
   },
   {  
      'ID':1,
      'Name':'John',
      'Age':28
   }
]
```

Is there an specific function in Python to do that?

Comment: Use `json` module. https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Python's json module.

```
import json
with open("filename.json", 'w') as f_out:
  json.dump(myListOfPeople, f_out)
```

More on the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json).

```
import json

myListOfPeople = [{'ID': 0, 'Name': 'Mary', 'Age': 25}, 
    {'ID': 1, 'Name': 'John', 'Age': 28}]

print(json.dumps(myListOfPeople))
```

Prints:

```
[{"ID": 0, "Name": "Mary", "Age": 25}, {"ID": 1, "Name": "John", "Age": 28}]
```

To write to a file, use `json.dump(myListOfPeople, f)` where `f` is a file opened for writing.